# Page scrolling issue in cordova app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am facing an issue in my cordova app i.e after using @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen to hide status bar in splash screen and main activity and status bar plugin to hide status bar in js pages but some pages in my app doesn't scroll down.

Kindly suggest

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you use the plugin I mentioned in my answer in your last question to add the Android theme? Can you post your config.xml?

Comment: Yes i used that but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android theme to hide the status bar and navigation bar you can remove the plugin you were using for hiding the status/navigation bar. It may be conflicting.

Comment: @android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen hide status bar only at splash screen to hide status bar in full app I used status bar plugin of cordova  and android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar.Fullscreen doesn't hide navigation bar even at splash screen and cordova navigationbar plugin is used to hide navigation bar